# slideToggle is animating the div up and down continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I am using slideToggle to make my header move with the page once scrollTop hit the 100. But once the scrollbar reaches to 100 and more, it keeps animating up and down for few moment.
Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var ScrollTop    = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(ScrollTop>=100){
       $('#main_header').removeClass("relative");
       $('#main_header').addClass("fixed");
       $('#main_header').slideToggle("slow");
   }else if(ScrollTop<=99){
       $('#main_header').removeClass("fixed");
       $('#main_header').addClass("relative");
   }
});
```

please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem on https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Seems you need to use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) i.e. `$('#main_header').stop(true).slideToggle("slow");`

Comment: This is happening because when you add the class "fixed" to your header, it is pulled out of page flow and hence the scroll goes up again equal to header's height. Now, scroll condition has changed, so it removed the class "fixed". Once added, the scroll is again more than threshold. That's why it keeps moving up and down when you are within that range. Once you have crossed that range, where addition/removal of header height does not change your scroll condition, it starts working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying to the browser, whenever the user scrolls down the page, see how far they have travelled. If they have travelled more than 99, then slide that header, otherwise do some other class toggling.

So let's say they scroll to 120, it will slide. Then they scroll down more to 140, it will slide. You have no check in place on whether it has already slid down, thus it will keep doing it. A simple approach would be to just add a boolean: -

```
var toggled = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
   var ScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (ScrollTop >= 100 && !toggled) {
       $('#main_header')
           .removeClass("relative")
           .addClass("fixed")
           .stop() // stop any prev animation
           .css('display', 'none') // force hide so it slides
           .slideToggle("slow");

       toggled = true; // won't enter again until set to false
   } else if (ScrollTop <= 99 && toggled) {
       $('#main_header').removeClass("fixed");
       $('#main_header').addClass("relative");

       toggled = false; // scrolled back up, can now slideToggle again!
   }
});
```

Comment: @mauzzamali try changing `slideToggle` to `slideDown`

Comment: I did!! slideDown is not animating it.. it is falling quickly and I gave the slow parameter as well but the result is same.

Comment: @mauzzamali just before the slideToggle, try saying `$('#main_header').css('display', 'none')`

Comment: @mauzzamali sure - the reason it was not happening first time is because the toggle thought it was already present (as the header was displaying block or equivalent), so making it display none forces it to retrigger the slide.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.stop()` method:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var ScrollTop    = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(ScrollTop>=100) {
        $('#main_header').removeClass("relative");
        $('#main_header').addClass("fixed");
        $('#main_header').stop(true).slideToggle("slow");
    } else if(ScrollTop<=99) {
        $('#main_header').removeClass("fixed");
        $('#main_header').addClass("relative");
    }
});
```